# VS Code Python import path when starting in a subfolder does not behave the same in VS Code and at run time

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a sample Python application that I'm playing around with in VS Code. The folder structure that I have is that the application is in a sub-folder. The readme.md and code-workspace files and the like are in the root of the project, and then I have a sub-folder for my application code.

I have a file that represents the entry point of the application, and other files containing supporting logic in the same folder. When I try to import from those files VS Code wants me to put a period before the module (file) name.

```
from .my_code_file import my_class
```

But that errors when I run the application. It runs just fine if I remove the leading period.

```
from my_code_file import my_class
```

Why does VS Code Intelisense think I need a period in front of the module name?

This is a representation of the file and folder structure:

```
|-AppCode
| |-my_code_file.py
| |-application_entry_point.py
|
|-readme.md
|-MyProject.code-workspace
```

Comment: Please include your file/folder structure and include the error message(s) and/or linter warnings that you're running into. Someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that when importing other files, the standard import statement should be: "`from AppCode.my_code_file import my_class`", and VScode starts from the parent folder of the currently opened file by default. Obviously, VSCode cannot find the folder "`AppCode`" from the folder "`AppCode`", we can use the following two methods to help VSCode find "`my_code_file`":

1. Please add the following statement, which adds the path of the file to be imported to the system path, and VSCode can find her in the system path:

> ```
> import os,sys
> sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
> ```

[image]

If `Pylint` reports an error "`Unable to import'AppCode.my_code_file`", but the code can run, we can use

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--disabled=E0602"
    ]
```

to turn off this warning.

2.We can also use "`from my_code_file import my_class`", the code can be executed to get the result.

[image]

If `Python` reports an error "`unresolved import'my_code_file`", but the code can run, we can use

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
        "unresolved-import",
    ],
```

to close this warning.

Reference: [readable-pylint-messages](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#undefined-variable).

Answer (score 1):

I was running into issues just like this recently and after some googling I found several ppl recommending I download microsoft's new Python extension called Pylance.

I've been using it for about a week and it solved all of my issues I was having that involved my application being confused w/ file structure. I'd recommend giving it a try!
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

Cheers,
-Andrew